# Serialization of CassandraPageRequest

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I'm using spring-data-cassandra in my project, and I want to provide pagination-like functionality (no random access, no particular page select - just forward fetching). I'm able to achieve this effect with a method described in this PR:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/pull/114

However, I want to serialize Pageable object returned by `Slice.nextPageable()` function to expose this functionality over REST interface. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring but look for something like "Paging state" in documentation. I'm using paging state value in my python project to expose pagination functionality over REST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to force cast Pageable object to CassandraPageRequest and then use .getPagingState to retrieve a wanted object. After serialization, it's possible to create PagingState back from string and add page size to create PageRequest. Kinda tricky and undocumented, but works. Remember to check if next page exists and if Pageable is really CassandraPageRequest. Sample code below:

```
// Serialize pageabele
if (isNull(pageable) || pageable.isUnpaged() || !(pageable instanceof 
    CassandraPageRequest)) {
        return null;
}

final CassandraPageRequest cassandraPageRequest = ((CassandraPageRequest) 
pageable);
if (isNull(cassandraPageRequest.getPagingState())) {
    return null;
}

return cassandraPageRequest.getPagingState().toString();

// Create request from serialized object
CassandraPageRequest.of(PageRequest.of(0, pageSize),
        PagingState.fromString(serializedPagingState));
```

Here's also issue on SpringData Jira.
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-565#add-comment